# SSH remote connection closes immediately after login

Tags: ssh, webserver

When I try to connect via ssh to a certain web server I get immediately after successful login the message `Connection to xx.xx.xx.xx closed.`

I wanted to post what I get in verbose mode, but unfortunately I get the message `This looks like spam.` when I try to post the whole output, so I just can post excerpts, sorry …

```
dave@VideoBeast ~ % ssh -vvv mylogin@xx.xx.xx.xx
OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
[…]
debug1: Connection established.
[…]
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to xx.xx.xx.xx ([xx.xx.xx.xx]:22).
[…]
Last login: Sat Jul 10 08:44:35 2021 from 79.206.178.207
debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eow
debug2: channel 0: chan_shutdown_read (i0 o0 sock -1 wfd 4 efd 6 [write])
debug2: channel 0: input open -> closed
debug3: receive packet: type 96
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: channel 0: chan_shutdown_write (i3 o1 sock -1 wfd 5 efd 6 [write])
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug3: receive packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 0: almost dead
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 0: send close
debug3: send packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: is dead
debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t4 r0 i3/0 o3/0 e[write]/0 fd -1/-1/6 sock -1 cc -1)

debug3: send packet: type 1
debug3: fd 1 is not O_NONBLOCK
Connection to xx.xx.xx.xx closed.
Transferred: sent 2344, received 2868 bytes, in 1.1 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 2176.7, received 2663.3
debug1: Exit status 1
dave@VideoBeast ~ %
```

What could be the reason? Is there something I could fix on my Mac or should the server administrator something?

For your hints and thoughts many thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you're actually supposed to be able to login to that web server like this? Some servers are configured to drop the connection or only allow specific commands to be performed directly - and not allowing an actual shell.

Comment: Yes, the administrator ensured me that it should work with this login credentials.